# How to know from css if a select is opened

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to know in css if a select is opened or not? I want to change the the dropdown image when my select is opened.

Comment: using jQuery it's easy to know

Comment: I want to write a css selector for it

Comment: Not in CSS, but you can add a class with jQuery and then do your thing in CSS using that class.

Comment: this might help you.. but it has jquery.. http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/.. thru css you can style select box like this http://codepen.io/bephf/pen/ogNBYW

Comment: Here is a list of all pseudo-selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp - What you're asking is simply not there, use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know if the select is focused

```
select:focus {}
```

Most times this indicates it is open, but not always. To know it 100% sure, you need javascript.

I hope it helps.

Comment: this is the closest solution with css

Answer (score 1):

You can make it possible with a bootstrap type of drop down.Incluse bootstrap css and js file in your project

step1-Create a Dropdown list as follows.

```
<div id="ddl" class="dropup">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Step2-Now for that div you can assign a toogle kind of event.

```
$('#ddl').toogle({
if(class='dropup')
{
//Here  assign a class to the div(dropup or drop down )
}
else
{
//Here  assign a class to the div(dropup or drop down )
}
});
```